# How can flesh be the only reliable parchment to contain magical ink?

Tags: magic, humans

The ancient empire of Insamouth was a world power in the ancient world that worshipped eldritch gods and practiced magic. It was able to conquer many nation's and subject their people to slavery. Their most feared ritual was saved for human sacrifices and executions, which involved the flaying of a victim.  What is special is what the skin of an individual is used for. It's main purpose is to be used as parchment and to bind books. Flesh is used to write and hold magical ink. This ink is the basis for performing spells, and is only able to be contained in flesh stripped from a living victim.

Why would this be the case?

Comment: I really don't see what all the gore details add to the question

Comment: Boiling anything alive would not make a softer skin. It would make the skin break and make removing from flesh easier. Also I doubt anyone would move after being boiled alive. And flesh is below the skin. First you need to skin something to remove the flesh from the bones. I think you misuse and swap beetwen "flesh" (as in meat, muscles) and skin (as in the epidermis). And the skin hold ink as skin hold the ink. In your question there is no description of how the magic ink differ from regular ink.

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels. It is my opinion that you have way too much gore here to be in line with Worldbuilding.SE's policies.

Answer (score 2):

The flaying of a live victim results in a high degree of pain [citation needed]. This in turn results in the release of several pain related enzymes/chemicals into the victim which is relayed to the skin as it's being slowly stripped from the body.

The ink is nothing special. Just your ordinary magical ink that you can get from any Flourish and Blotts. Although I have heard you get a better deal in Knockturn Alley. Anyway, as I was saying, the ink is nothing special, however, when exposed to the terror enzymes in the flayed skin it produces a heightened magical ability and amplifies the spells. Because...magic.

Any self-respecting magic user knows to use ink/tortured skin combination for the *best* results. Can we help it if over the years, some have come to believe it's just *not possible* to do magic any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Live muscles contain [ATP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenosine_triphosphate), which is the energy source for the cells, and muscles contain more of them because of their role in motion.

> the human body recycles its own body weight equivalent in ATP each day

Apparently it is also the energy source for the spells written with the ink you mention, and it has to be taken from living subjects, else it would degrade.

Answer (score 0):

**Blood magic**

Magic is something done by the living. You don't expect a rock to do magic. Magic also need to be contained by the living, or the very least used to live. The blood sacrifice of stripping the flesh is a form of magic on it's own, so the skin will perserve the ability to 'store' the magic. Creatures capable of magic are of course best. A cow can't do magic, so why would it be able to hold more then the magic equivalent of moving a grain of sand?

Alternatively to killing the persons you could also have 'living' books. Keep them locked away in a tight dry cell without light or too much oxigen, just like a library with incredibly old books. Get them out of storage when they're required to be read. The magic ink is more powerful than writings on dead flesh this way. If they do happen to die, you can still preserve the writings in the books of flesh.